# Pandas vectorization for a multiple data frame operation

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to increase the speed of an operation within pandas and I have learned that it is generally best to do so via using vectorization. The problem I am looking for help with is vectorizing the following operation.

Setup:

`df1 =` a table with a date-time column, and city column

`df2 =` another (considerably larger) table with a date-time column, and city column

The Operation:

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    for x, row2 in df1.iterrows():
        if row['date-time'] - row2['date-time'] > pd.Timedelta('8 hours') and row['city'] == row2['city']:
            df2.at[i, 'result'] = True
            break
```

As you might imagine, this operation is insanely slow on any dataset of a decent size. I am also just beginning to learn pandas vector operations and would like some help in figuring out a more optimal way to solve this problem

Comment: Can you explain what the operation is doing? If you are only looking to flag whether there is a row in df1 that at least occurs 8 hours after a row in df2 (for the same city) then you can do that with some combination of a groupby then map. Otherwise `pd.merge_asof` can check for rows within some tolerance after exactly matching on city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is `merge()` with `numpy.where()` to achieve the same result.

Since you don't have a reproducible sample in your question, kindly consider this:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[24,20,15,10,5], 'city':['A','B','C','D','E']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'time':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14], 'city':['A','B','C','F','G','H','D']})

>>> df1
   time city
0    24    A
1    20    B
2    15    C
3    10    D
4     5    E

>>> df2
   time city
0     2    A
1     4    B
2     6    C
3     8    F
4    10    G
5    12    H
6    14    D
```

From what I understand, you only need to get all the rows in your `df2` that has a value in the `city` column in `df1`, where the difference in the dates are at least 9 hours (greater than 8 hours).

To do that, we need to merge on your city column:

```
>>> new_df = df2.merge(df1, how = 'inner', left_on = 'city', right_on = 'city')
>>> new_df
   time_x city  time_y
0       2    A      24
1       4    B      20
2       6    C      15
3      14    D      10
```

`time_x` basically is the time in your `df2` dataframe, and `time_y` is from your `df1`.

Now we need to check the difference of those times and retain the one that will give a greater than 8 value in doing so, by using `numpy.where()` flagging them to do the filtering later:

```
>>> new_df['flag'] = np.where(new_df['time_y'] - new_df['time_x'] > 8, ['Retain'], ['Remove'])
>>> new_df
   time_x city  time_y    flag
0       2    A      24  Retain
1       4    B      20  Retain
2       6    C      15  Retain
3      14    D      10  Remove
```

Now that you have that, you can simply filter your `new_df` by the flag column, removing the column in the final output as such:

```
>>> final_df = new_df[new_df['flag'].isin(['Retain'])][['time_x', 'city', 'time_y']]
>>> final_df
   time_x city  time_y
0       2    A      24
1       4    B      20
2       6    C      15
```

And there you go, no looping needed. Hope this helps :D

Comment: Nice! This does help a ton! For me this is a lot like it was learning recursion. Just need to retrain my brain to think outside the box. The only issue I can foresee with this solution is exceeding available memory. I.E. if you have 5 million rows in df2 (time_x) and you average 5 overlapping cities with different times in final_df, the resulting new_df will be huge (25 million rows minimum). What do you recommend doing in this case?